# Nextjs SSG slow at first load

Tags: next.js, vercel, static-site-generation

I deployed a Nextjs app on Vercel. I found that the response time of the SSG pages with `getStaticProps` is slower in the first page load. The subsequent page load are instant. Why is this the case?

I expect that all page loads should be instant because they are cached in the CDN during build time. I am sure that the pages are SSG because I view them tagged as SSG in the build logs. What am I missing here? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static files are not in the CDN on first request after building.

> Pull-based CDNs load the data on the first request and keep it around until it expires.  Vercel handles most aspects of our infrastructure like a pull-based CDN

[Source](https://vercel.com/blog/edge-config-ultra-low-latency-data-at-the-edge)

Answer (score 0):

**The problem vercel server work like serverless if your website no one call him for a while Vercel will set your app to idle mode**

Comment: If deployment is on a server different from Vercel, will SSG pages be cached by default? @Jawad Fadel

Comment: I am not sure I use  app dir.